# Error loading R packages due to group policy

Tags: r, dll

I'm trying to load R packages using `library(package)` or `require(package)`.  I have been using the packages on this machine (work computer) for a while, but now get an error. I think the group policy was updated to not allow .dll files.

The error I get is:

```
library(ggplot2)

Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/UserName/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/digest/libs/i386/digest.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator.
```

Is there another way to load the packages that will avoid this error?

Comment: Have you contacted your system administrator?

Comment: Yes, but it's a slow process to change, so I'm looking for something I can use in the meantime.  I'm really wondering if there's a way to load the functions from the packages similar to how you can create your own functions.